# add value to List from another class threw NullRefernceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add value from another class to the list created in another class. I have set up a very simple experiment but it always throw me the error.

the first class is simply gameObject script which attached to the object

```
public class gameObject : Agent
{
    public Area area;

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        var testData = new test
        {
            name = "test value",
        };
       area.testList.Add(testData);
    }

}
```

and I try to add that value to the list in another class as shown belows

```
public class test
{
    public string name;
}

public class Area : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public List<test> testList =  new List<test>()
}
```

why the value always return `null` ? it work properly if I add the data with in the area class

Comment: `testList` initialized in ``VoxelArea`` what is the `Area` class?

Comment: @Sajid that probably from mistyped, I had corrected it thanks

Comment: Try to initialize just Area,like ``Area area = new Area()``

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `testList` list in `VoxelArea` class but you are using `Area`.

replace `Area` with `VoxelArea` or initialize `area.testList` and `area` before adding.

```cs
public class gameObject : Agent
{
    public Area area; //initialize Area 

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        var testData = new test
        {
            name = "test value",
        };
        //area = new Area(); //initialize Area 
        area.testList = new List<test>();//<--NOTE THIS
        area.testList.Add(testData);
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't the "area" property need to be initialized too?

Comment: @PeonProgrammer Thanks for guidance

Comment: @FarhadZamani it seems to work but now I've got "You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all" instead  ?

Comment: @James I don't know about `unity3d` but in `c#` you must in initialize `List` type and classes before adding a new value.

Comment: @FarhadZamani I have sorted out! thank you. Turns out I also need to attach gameObject that area script attach along with in the gameObject script to initiate it